# mv command not working while running in github actions

Tags: reactjs, linux, github, github-pages, github-actions

Simply I want to publish my react app on github pages so I want to move the build folder to docs folder
and I am running react build using github actions

my integrate.yml looks like this

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.5

      - name: Download Modules
        run: npm ci

      - name: React Build 
        run: |
          npm run build
          ls -a
          mv build docs --verbose
          ls -a
```

The output also shows that the folder is renamed

this is the output -

```
Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

.
..
.git
.github
.gitignore
README.md
build
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
src
renamed 'build' -> 'docs'
.
..
.git
.github
.gitignore
README.md
docs
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
src
```

I cannot see any error or some form of wrong prompt

here is my github repository
[Github Repo](https://github.com/YugankSingh/react-cart)

Comment: I suggest following the workflow implementation used in [this article](https://codeburst.io/deploying-a-react-app-using-github-pages-and-github-actions-7fc14d380796) which perform the same operation (deploying a react app on github pages).

Comment: the article is asking for subscrtiption, if you would tell me the name of workflow then it would be really great

Comment: Sure, the workflow used in this article can be found here: https://github.com/ClydeDz/create-react-app-ghpages-demo/blob/step-2/.github/workflows/build-deploy.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command was working but the code changes in the local repository of actions does not automatically publish,
you need to commit them inorder to the changes